# how to write a file on one controller and read the same in another controller in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to implement a functionality in nodejs. I have two different controllers in my node application. I has the responsibility to store the file (abc.xlsx) into local folder(mylocation) using fs module and i have done it successfully. And in my another controller i have to read the locally stored file(abc.xlsx).

Is it possible. Everytime i want to write a file from one controller and read the same from another controller. I have tried something as like the following..

```
exports.controller1 = function(req,res){

if(req.files.file){
     fs.readFile(req.files.file.path,function(err,data){
        var fileName = req.files.file.name;
        getfileName(fileName);
        some logic goes here......
     });
 }

}

 function getFileName(fileName){
      console.log(fileName);
 }

exports.controller2 = function(req,res){
    getFileName(fileName);
    var filePath = fileName;
    my logic goes here...
}
```

Need some help to get the fileName or the filePath to read a file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `controller2` where does the `fileName` variable come from? I'd expect it to come in the request but it doesn't.

Comment: fileName comes from the function called getFileName(fileName)

Comment: It can't. You call it with the parameter `fileName` but it returns no value. And as filename is a String it gets passed by value, not by reference so any changes to that value in the function doesn't get populated outside the function. Unless you mutate the global state that is :-)